# Jquery construye el boton pero no lo muestra

Tags: html, jquery

Buen Dia comunidad,necesito un poco de ayuda con algo que pueda ser un poco obvio pero soy nuevo con jquery.
Resulta que estoy contruyendo una tabla dinamica y a la hora de clickear para agregar un row nuevo, me construye todo el objeto correctamente, sin embargo el boton no lo muestra de la misma forma que el row original.

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Jquery el button con el id agrega es el que quiero que se vea como la imagen.

````
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        var numTr = $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length;
        $('#tab_logic').append("<tr id='addr'><td> " + (numTr + 1)
            + "<button id='agrega' class='btn - floating btn - success' style='border - radius: 50 %;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon - plus'></i></button></td>                                                                                                           <td><select name='product" +
            numTr + "' type='text'      style='height 60px;'    class='form-control output-md' /> </td>                         <td><output name='descripcion" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    class='form-control output-md'></td>                                                    <td><output name='costo" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    style='height 60px;'    class='form-control input-md'></td>                             <td><input name='margen" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    min='0' step='0.01'     style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md' /></td>      <td><output name='precio" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    style='height 60px;'    class='form-control output-md'/> </td>                          <td><input name='cantidad" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    min='0' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'/></td>                       <td><output name='precioTotal" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    style='height 60px;'    class='form-control output-md'  /> </td>                        <td><input name='tipoCambio" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    min='0' style='height 60px;'  class='form-control input-md'/></td>                      <td><output name='precioFinal" +
            numTr + "' type='number'    style='height 60px;'    class='form-control output-md'/></td>                           <td><textarea name='notas" +
            numTr + "' type='text'      style='height 60px; width: 150px; resize:none;' class='form-control textarea-md'/>      </td> </tr>");

    }); ```

HTML


```   <tr class="mycontainer" id="producto">
                            <td>
                                1
                                <button id="agrega" class="btn-floating btn-success " style="border-radius: 50%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            </td>                            <td>
                                <select id="product" style="height:60px; width:90px;" data-live-search="true" class="product form-control">
                                    <option>Seleccionar</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="error">Seleccione un Producto</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="descripcion">
                                <output type="number" id="descripcion" style="height:60px; width:80px;" class=" descripcion form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="costo">
                                <output type="number" id="costo" style="height:60px; width:80px;" class=" costo form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="margen">
                                <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" style="height:60px; width:120px;" placeholder="0,00%" id="margen" class=" margen form-control" />
                                <span class="error">Ingrese el % de margen de utilidad</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="precio">
                                <output type="number" id="precio" style="height:60px; width:80px;" class="precio form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="cantidad">
                                <input type="number" min="0" id="cantidad" style="height:60px; width:80px;" placeholder="0" class="cantidad form-control" />
                                <span class="error">Ingrese una cantidad</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="precioTotal">
                                <output type="text" id="precioTotal" style="height:60px; width:80px;" class="precioTotal form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="tipoCambio">
                                <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" placeholder="600" style="height:60px; width:100px;" id="tipoCambio" class="tipoCambio form-control" />
                                <span class="error">Ingrese un tipo de cambio del $</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="precioFinal">
                                <output type="number" id="precioFinal" style="height:60px; width:80px;" class="precioFinal form-control" onblur="total()" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="notas">
                                <textarea id="notas" style="height:60px; width:150px; resize:none;" placeholder="Notas" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>```


[![El circulo verde es el boton del html, los cuadros grises el boton que construye jquery pero no lo muestra como deberia][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBnEQ.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el javascript:

```
$('#tab_logic').append("<tr id='addr'><td> " + (numTr + 1)
        + "<button id='agrega' class='btn - floating btn - success' style='border - radius: 50 %;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon - plus'></i></button></td>**
```

Las clases agregadas tienen espacios de sobras.

```
class='btn - floating btn - success'
```

Las clases correctas son btn-floating y btn-success

Comment: Que verguenza jaja eso era, muchas gracias amigo!